# C# Telerik RadGrid subtract one automatically from column quantity when I press refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Telerik RadGrid in ASP.Net framework.  I create Buy procedure and when I press (Buy) it must subtract 1 from the column quantity.  It works correctly but if I press F5 or refresh, it continues subtracting 1 by 1.  Every refresh subtracts 1 from the quantity.  How can i prevent that?  [image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0fts.jpg)

Comment: First, please post actual code instead of a picture of your code.  Second, the code in your picture has nothing to do with subtraction.  Please post relevant code.

Comment: @Ken - I agree that the code should be posted here (and more of it).  However, the code posted does deal with subtraction.  Evidently, the OP deletes a record from the database and then rebinds the list (thus "subtracting" one from the recordset).

Comment: this is the procedure: create procedure _Delete

@ID int

   AS
   BEGIN
   update item
   set Quantity = Quantity-1
   where ID = @ID
   END ,and the code i gave it to you

Comment: guys i am asking my manager and he told me that this is one of the weakness and lack of .net when you press refresh it execute las command...
!?

Comment: @BiggsTRC, I noticed the call to _Delete but couldn't figure out how deleting a record would make sense when you want to decrement a counter.  :)  Now that we can see the code, perhaps the SP should be called something else, as it doesn't actually delete anything.

Comment: @user748057, anytime you press refresh when you POST something, the browser will ask you if you want to POST it again.  That happens on all pages, not just ASP.Net pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the refresh button after you submit, the browser will attempt to send the same values (via a POST method) to your site, and will usually ask you for confirmation before doing so.

If you wish to avoid this from happening, you can try the following:

- Send the user to another page (therefore hitting refresh will simply refresh the page)
- Maintain some state that the action occurred, and prevent your code from running again.  You could do that with a cookie or a session variable, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem a bit simplistic but how about adding the following constraint to your code:

```
    if(e.CommandName == "AddToBasket" && !page.IsPostback)
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: no man it did not work i debug it...i find that when i add && !page.IsPostback no execution for the code (it did not enter the function